# Get id of main div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the div id for a button and identify whether it's within one of two possible ids? For example, we have a call-to-action button that could be inside a div with the id="new" or id="current". Here are a few examples:

```
<div id="new">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cStatus()">Download</a>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="current">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cStatus()">Download</a>
</div>
```

It's possible the id could be in a parent or parent's parent div, such as this:

```
<div id="new">
    <div class="something">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cStatus()">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

or this:

```
<div id="new">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cStatus()">Download</a>
        </div
    </div>
</div>
```

We'd like our landing page developers to be able to develop the pages without having to ever touch the JavaScript for this functionality. We're ultimately trying to pass along this value in a URL string, such as this:

```
fileref.setAttribute("src", "https://oururl.html?cStatus=" + cStatus);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this slight modification: `onclick="cStatus(this)"` and then:

```
function cStatus(elem) {
    var els = [];
    while (elem) {
        els.unshift(elem);
        elem = elem.parentNode;
        if (elem.id == "new") {
            // has new
            break;
        } else if (elem.id == "current") {
            // has current
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you for posting a solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the `onclick` callback you can get the parent element using $(this).parent() and then check its id.

Comment: This won't work for a nested element (parent of parent)